# Legend Not Appearing on ggplot2 bar plot

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2

Given this data

```
> vec2df
   vec2  sd
1    9  0.5
2    7  0.2
3    8  0.3
4    9  1.0
```

And code

```
ggplot(vec2df,
       aes(seq_along(vec2), vec2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
       fill = c("red","blue","green","yellow")) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = vec2 - sd, ymax = vec2 + sd), 
                width = .2, position = position_dodge(.9), 
                legendPosition="top")
```

The legend is not showing up for some reason. Can someone tell me how to make it appear?

Comment: I think you need `legend.position` rather than `legendPosition`

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't map some variable to an aesthetic, it won't create a legend. Also, try making your `x` variable a factor, so it maps discrete the bars to discrete colours rather than a gradient. For example:

```
# Read data
vec2df <- read.table(textConnection("vec2  sd
1    9  0.5
2    7  0.2
3    8  0.3
4    9  1.0"))

# Plot
ggplot(vec2df,aes(x=as.factor(seq_along(vec2)), y=vec2)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=as.factor(seq_along(vec2))), stat='identity') +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue","green","yellow"))
```

I didn't add the error bars but that wasn't relevant to the question.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, say I had more than 4 bars. Maybe about 12 and three were of red, three blue, etc. How do I keep the legend as it is instead of expanding out into 12 bars?

Comment: You must map a variable onto each of those colours. For example if you had a column called `group` in `vec2df`, which was `group1` for all the red bars, and `group2` for all the blue bars, then you could say `aes(group=fill)` in the `geom_bar` function. The legend would then say `group1` or `group2` as labels.